# Adding Core Data Entity named Image creates compile errors

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swiftui

I have an existing project using Core Data but now I'm trying to add a new Entity called Image to the project and it does not compile.

I am using SwiftUI and all of the compile errors are about SwiftUI.

```
"Instance method *** requires that *** conforms to 'View'"
"Incorrect argument *** in call"
"Static method 'buildBlock' requires that *** conform to 'View'"
```

There is already and existing Entity in the project, it works find, but when adding this new one all the errors come up at compile time.

If this new created Entity is deleted, the errors go away and it compiles fine.

Tried clean build. Tried restarting Xcode.

Using Xcode 12

Errors:
[Xcode compile errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Od6Jo.png)

[Xcode compiler errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OsHtu.png)

Core Data Entities (Image is the new one):
[Core Data Entities](https://i.stack.imgur.com/axbuT.png)

Comment: Change the CoreData Image to something else. Image is already used by a SwiftUI View

Comment: :facepalm: how dumb of me LOL ... thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CoreData entity should be renamed as it is conflicting.